# z-index not displaying nested child behind parent

Tags: html, css

I created an Ad prototype for a client. And I am unable have child show-up underneath parent, even though their z-indexes are correct.

Please take a look - http://www.charuv.com/prototype/i4.html

**Steps to the issue**

1. Window scroll - scroll up having your mouse over the black background.
2. Content scroll - scroll up having your mouse over the device-simulator, the one with a thick white border.

Having done above , you would see following visual glitch (not sure if its fixable)

**CSS issue**

Video inside #ad-box is overlapping the super-parent - #get-frame, but not the immediate parent #c1. 
So the structure is like -- **#get-frame -> #c1 -> #ad-box**

**CSS rules**

Following are the CSS rules for above three

```
#get-frame {
margin: 6% auto 0;
overflow: auto;
border-width: 72px 25px 63px;
border-style: solid;
border-color: #fff;
box-shadow: 0 0 50px rgba(0, 0, 0, .8);
border-radius: 50px;
z-index: 999999;
position: relative
}

#c1 {
z-index: 99999;
background-position: left top;
background-attachment: fixed;
background-image: url("blue.jpg");
background-attachment: fixed
}

#ad-box {
position: fixed;
margin: 11.5% 26.2%;
top: 0;
left: 0;
overflow: auto;
z-index: 99999
}
```

Appreciate your time.

Answer (score 0):

Remove `position: relative; z-index: 99999;` from `#c1`. This way there is no parent context and the fixed position `#ad-box` is free to interact with z-indexes elsewhere in the DOM structure.